# Which is the class of Wagtail Pages?

Tags: class, wagtail

I have developed some classes with Wagtail Page as base class,for example InfoPage.In the application I must know which class is used.

If I use "**class**" I get "<class 'wagtail.core.models.Page'>" but not for example InfoPage.

How can I get the name of the class?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the class through [`page.specific_class`](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.core.models.Page.specific_class).

When you perform a database lookup where the page type of the result is not known in advance - such as `Page.objects.filter(slug='news')` or `page.get_children()` - it will be returned as an instance of the base `Page` class, where only the common fields such as title and slug are available. This is because fetching the complete page data would require additional database queries, which might be unnecessary (e.g. if you're just outputting a listing of page titles). To access the full page object in its most specific form, use `page.specific`, or if you just want to know the class without doing the additional database fetch, use `page.specific_class`. Page querysets also have a `specific()` method for retrieving all the specific instances in one go.